# Turning on a 5v circuit with an 3.3v control signal (from a Raspberry PI)

Tags: transistors, timer, switching

I want to run a NE555 timer in astable mode, but I only want it to turn on when a 3.3v is supplied, I want to make use of a transistor to do the switching.

At the moment i am using a 2N2222 transistor, but cant seem to get the design right. Can someone please help me to design the switching transistor.

[image: Will this circuit work?]

Will this circuit work?

Comment: What circuit are you struggling over? There is a schematic editor available for use when editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp7slz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using a transistor to switch a subcircuit of higher voltage / higher current is very common in electronics.  The biggest thing to take away from this is NPN transistors (which the 2n2222 is) "connects your circuit to ground" which PNP's connect your circuit to the positive supply.

Trying to use the NPN to connect to the positive voltage will not work without extra circuitry, and the same is true for the dual scenario with the PNP.  R2 is an absolute necessity, it limits the current into the base of your transistor.  This is sized to limit the voltage across the two terminals of the transistor acting as a switch (because an ideal switch would have 0 volts across those two terminals.)  R1 helps keep the transistor off when your RPI is not on or not driving that pin high or low.  This resistor is a nicety, and you won't see this resistor as much when you google the "NPN as a switch" string.

Comment: The 555 timer will later work with a battery so i dont want to supply power to it at all until the PI activates the transistor as a switch.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the 2N2222 to hold the 555 oscillator capacitor discharged then the 555 can never oscillate until the base drive to the 2N2222 is removed and the transistor open circuits.

[image]

See pin 7 - it's called the discharge pin. Connect collector to pin 7 and emitter to GND then you can force a permanent discharge by driving base current into the BJT.